# Regex to replace STR in dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to replace 'HHN PPP', 'HHN CMV' and many more starting with 'HHN' with only '**HNN**', considering that there are other brands start with different codes which should not be changed.

I tried the following code, but it didn't work

```
DF.replace({'Brand':r'^HHN'},{'Brand':'HNN'})
```

Here is sample of my dataframe:

```
  Code    Brand    Serial Number   Account         Date        
 ------ --------- --------------- --------- ------------------ 
  SRS    HHN CMV          113912     10984   29/01/2020 14:01  
  SRR    HHN CMV          518506     88332   01/06/2020 17:11  
  SRR    HHN CMV           82020     50509   01/06/2020 16:55  
  SRR    HHN PPP           81718     73777   01/06/2020 15:42  
  SRR    HHN PPP          947233     92812   01/06/2020 15:31  
  SRR    HHN PPP          246639     97051   01/06/2020 15:09  
  SRR    HHN PPP          344475     15869   01/06/2020 12:47  
  SRR    KNN PV           176513     19982   01/06/2020 11:28  
  SRR    KNN PV           193908     13462   01/06/2020 11:20
```

Thanks.

Comment: `DF['Brand'] = DF['Brand'].str.replace(r'^HHN (?:PPP|CMV)$', 'HNN')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
DF['Brand'] = DF['Brand'].str.replace(r'^HHN\s.*', 'HNN')
```

Here,

- `^` - matches start of string
- `HHN` - `HHN` string
- `\s` - a whitespace char
- `.*` - the rest of the string.
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use regex you can do this:

```
df.replace(['HHN PPP','HHN CMV'], 'HNN')
```

if you want to replace in just one columns you can set the column

```
df.replace({'Brand':['HHN PPP','HHN CMV']}, 'HNN')
```

Comment: Actually I need to use regex, this is only sample of my dataframe. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following code and it seems to be working.

DF.replace({'Brand':r'^HHN.*'},{'Brand':'HNN'},regex=True,inplace= True)

The * Matches 0 or more occurrences of preceding expression.

The . Matches any character except newline

You may check the following links

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm